# How can I expire token on client in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect

I use angular-oauth2-oidc lib in Angular and Identity Server on my project. And I use another client is MVC.
When I sign out on MVC I want logout in Angular. But token is not expire in Angular app.
When I go to Angular app I get authorize user. I get it

> this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken(); // true

My angular settings:

```
const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
        clientId: this.configurationService.config.audience,
        issuer: `${this.configurationService.config.issuer}`,
        redirectUri: `${location.origin}/auth-callback`,
        loginUrl: `${this.configurationService.config.issuer}/connect/authorize`,
        logoutUrl: `${this.configurationService.config.issuer}/connect/revocation`,
        requestAccessToken: true,
        clearHashAfterLogin: true,
        responseType: 'id_token token',
        sessionChecksEnabled: true,
        showDebugInformation: true,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: `${this.configurationService.config.issuer}/Account/Logout`,
        requireHttps: this.configurationService.config.requireHttps,
        scope: this.configurationService.config.scope,
    };
```

Identity settings:

```
    new Client
    {
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
        RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,                    
        AccessTokenLifetime = coreSettings.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetimeInSeconds,
        IdentityTokenLifetime = coreSettings.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetimeInSeconds,
        UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        ClientId = "jsclient",
        ClientName = "JavaScript client",
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("personal-cabinet".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        RequireConsent = false,
        RedirectUris =
        {
            $"{coreSettings.PersonalCabinet}/auth-callback"
        },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris =
        {
            coreSettings.IdentityServer
        },

        AllowedCorsOrigins =
        {
            coreSettings.PersonalCabinetApiService,
            coreSettings.PersonalCabinet
        },

        AllowedScopes =
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            "personal-cabinet-api"
        }
    }
```

How can I expire token in Angular? Maybe need I add something logout url?
I add in settings

> logoutUrl: `${this.configurationService.config.issuer}/connect/revocation`

but it does not work.

Maybe need I send something url for logout?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: how are you storing the token client-side? can't you just delete the token on logout? Or do you have a use case where it has to be expired?

Comment: @tcrite I can get token in _this.oauthService.getAccessToken()_. oauthService - class instance from OAuthService from 'angular-oauth2-oidc'. This class has logout method - _this.oauthService.logOut();_ But how can I call this method from Identity Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Session Management technique, which is an OIDC standard: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

The angular-oauth2-oidc library supports this: https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/session-checks.html You would have to check how to enable it in Identity Server.